# Import JSZip in Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, typescript, jszip

I am having troubles while importing the JSZip library in my Angular 2 project.
I followed the following steps in order to change the project configuration:

1 - Install JSZip using NPM

```
npm install jszip --save
```

2 - Change systemjs.config.js as follows

```
var map = {
    ...
    'jszip':                      'node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js'
};
```

3 - Import the dependency within the component that requires it

```
import JSZip from 'jszip';
```

Then, I tried using the main JSZip constructor to attach some files, but I am getting a web error stating that the constructor is not defined. Besides, the Typescript editor I am using is not able to find the definition for it.

Did I miss something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 48):

For those who want to know how it ended, the problem was in the import.
The following is the correct import:

```
import * as JSZip from 'jszip';
```

Then, it is used as follows:

```
let zipFile: JSZip = new JSZip();
```

Comment: If you're using JSZip 3.x you can also get the Typescript type definitions with: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jszip

Comment: I got this error when trying your solution Unexpected token ':'
    at Object../node_modules/setimmediate/setImmediate.js (main.js:32023)

Answer (score 4):

There is a typo and it should be:

```
import * as JSZip from 'jszip';
let zipFile: JSZip = new JSZip();
```

Answer (score 2):

With the current JSZip version (3.10.1), we need to use this command:

```
import JSZip from 'jszip';
```

then use:

```
let zipFile: JSZip = new JSZip();
```

After google for a while, I had to read the typescript code of JSZip to find out this. Hope this will help someone else.