# Using jszip with angular 2

Tags: angular, jszip

I am trying to implement [JsZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/)  in angular 2 so I can zip files users have uploaded but cannot seem to get it to work.

In my visual studio code it seems happy when I complile I get:

ERROR in C:/wamp/www/nationalgrid/public_cli/src/app/app.module.ts (26,24): Cannot find module 'jszip'.

I have looked at and tried what was suggested in [stack overflow where user states what import statements to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097159/import-jszip-in-angular-2-project)

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. If someone has a working example in plunker that would be best.

Appmodule code:

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { BsDropdownModule, PaginationModule, TabsModule} from 'ng2-bootstrap';
import { CustomFormsModule } from 'ng2-validation';
import { Ng2TableModule } from 'ng2-table/ng2-table';
import { DatePickerModule } from 'ng2-datepicker';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpService } from './services/http.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ToasterModule, ToasterService } from 'angular2-toaster';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';


//Third Party Components
import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/core';
import { FileSelectDirective, FileDropDirective} from 'ng2-file-upload';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
import { ToastModule } from 'ng2-toastr';
import { JWBootstrapSwitchModule } from 'jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2';
import { BsModalModule } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';
import { SelectModule} from 'ng2-select';
import * as JSZip from 'jszip';

//Needed for special routes handling - 
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { Routes} from '@angular/router';
const routes: Routes = [];


/*** Project Imports ***/

/*!! Grids !!*/
import { UserListGrid} from './grid/index';
import { FileListGrid} from './grid/index';
import { ReportByAccessLogsListGrid} from './grid/index';
import { ReportByCompanyListGrid} from './grid/index';
import { ReportByUserListGrid} from './grid/index';
import { ReportByTotalsListGrid} from './grid/index';
import { ReportByBusinessclassListGrid} from './grid/index';

/*!! Models !!*/


/*!! Services !!*/

    /*!! Admin Area  !!*/

/* Admin Options*/
import { UserService } from './services/index';
import { FileListService } from './services/index';
import { ManageUserService } from './services/index';


/* other areas*/
import { UserAuthService } from './services/index';
import { RenewalDocumentService } from './services/index';
import { RenewalOptionsService } from './services/index';
import { RememberMeService } from './services/index';
import { AppMessagingService } from './services/index';
import { LoaderService,  ExportToExcel} from './services/index';

import { JszipComponent } from './adminarea/admin_options/zipfiles/jszip.component';

/** AppCompoent import must always be the last import to ensure it have everything above **/
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations:
  [
    /* App Components*/
    AppComponent,

    /* !!! System Imports !!! */
    FileDropDirective, FileSelectDirective,

    /*!! Admin Area  !!*/  
    JszipComponent,

    TestUserComponent,

  ...
  ],


imports: [

/* !!! System Imports !!! */
  JSZip,
  ToastModule,
  ChartsModule,
  TabsModule,
  BsModalModule,
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpModule,
  DataTablesModule.forRoot(),
  ToasterModule,
  SelectModule,
  NgbModule.forRoot(),
  BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
  CustomFormsModule,
  Ng2TableModule,
  PaginationModule.forRoot(),
  DatePickerModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  JWBootstrapSwitchModule,
  // Add routes to the app routing should always be the last import
  routing,
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
  ],


  entryComponents:
  [

  ],

  providers: 
  [
    /* !!! System Providers !!! */

    /* !!! Project Providers !!! */

    UserAuthService,
    AppMessagingService,
    CookieService,
    RememberMeService,
    ToasterService,
    ExportToExcel,
    HttpService,
    LoaderService,
    .

    /*!! Admin Area  !!*/
    /* Admin Options*/
    UserListGrid,
    UserService,
    FileListGrid,
    FileListService,
    ManageUserService,


    { provide: 'apiBase', useValue: 'http://localhost:81/NationalGrid/ci_ngi/api/' }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

part of my systemjs.config.js file:

```
   /**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      //app: 'app',
      app: 'ts_js/app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
      'ng2-file-upload': 'npm:ng2-file-upload',
      'ng2-uploader': 'npm:ng2-uploader',
      'ng2-toastr': 'npm:ng2-toastr',
      'ng2-charts': 'npm:ng2-charts',
      'angular2-cookie':            'npm:angular2-cookie',
      'ng2-pagination':            'npm:ng2-pagination',
      'ng2-bs3-modal':            'npm:ng2-bs3-modal',
      'jszip':                    'node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js'
    },
```

package.json file

```
    {
  "name": "ngi-app",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.3.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.22",
    "@types/file-saver": "0.0.1",
    "@types/jspdf": "1.1.31",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.50",
    "@types/xlsx": "0.0.34",
    "angular-datatables": "2.3.0",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.5",
    "angular2-multiselect-checkbox-dropdown": "^1.5.0",
    "angular2-select": "1.0.0-beta.3",
    "angular2-toaster": "3.0.1",
    "body-parser": "1.17.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "^2.4.0",
    "child_process": "1.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "datatables.net": "1.10.13",
    "datatables.net-dt": "1.10.13",
    "file-saver": "1.3.3",
    "https": "1.0.0",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json2csv": "3.7.3",
    "jspdf": "1.3.3",
    "jspdf-autotable": "2.3.2",
    "jszip": "^3.1.4",
    "jw-bootstrap-switch-ng2": "^1.0.4",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.13",
    "multer": "1.3.0",
    "mysql": "2.13.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "1.6.1",
    "ng2-bs-dropdown": "0.7.0",
    "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.11.10",
    "ng2-charts": "1.4.1",
    "ng2-datepicker": "1.8.3",
    "ng2-file-upload": "1.1.4-2",
    "ng2-pagination": "1.0.1",
    "ng2-select": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-slimscroll": "1.3.2",
    "ng2-toastr": "1.3.2",
    "ng2-validation": "3.9.1",
    "ng2-validators": "2.1.1",
    "node-cron": "1.1.3",
    "nodemailer": "4.0.1",
    "primeng": "^4.2.1",
    "rand-token": "0.3.0",
    "rxjs": "5.3.0",
    "swig": "1.4.2",
    "tls": "0.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "ts-xlsx": "0.0.11",
    "typings": "^2.0.1",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.3.1",
    "@types/datatables.net": "1.10.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "2.0.41",
    "@types/moment": "2.13.0",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "0.2.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect": "1.0.8",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.2.1",
    "nodemon": "1.11.0",
    "protractor": "4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "4.3.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.3",
    "typings": "^2.0.1",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5",
    "webpack": "3.4.1"
  }
}
```

Thanks a million
Andy

Comment: How did you install jszip, and could you please show app.module.ts.

Comment: Hi Richard thanks for the comment just got back from leave, I used npm to install jszip, below is app module:

...
import * as JSZip from 'jszip';
...

import { JszipComponent } from './adminarea/admin_options/zipfiles/jszip.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations:
  [  
JszipComponent
...
],


imports: [
JSZip
...]

If you need more info then would need to attached a file if possible
Thanks Andy

Comment: You could just edit the question and paste in the code. What you show looks ok, I guess the next question is - whats' on line 26 of app,module.ts

Comment: I have added my app module code above but removed some imports etc where not related to shorten it a bit.

line 26 of App module is "import * as JSZip from 'jszip';"

Answer (score 0):

All the info given indicates the correct install and import procedure has been followed. I've reproduced the steps and got no compile error.

The error message points to a fault in the npm install, could you please check the following

- Open package.json *of your project* and see if the following line is there

  ```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "jszip": "^3.1.4",
  ```

  Let me know if your version is different.
- Take a look in the node_modules folder of the project for the jszip sub-folder. 
  Open the package.json *in the jszip folder* and see if it has this line

  ```
  "main": "./lib/index",
  ```
- Open lib/index.js and see that the first functional line is

  ```
  function JSZip() {
  ```

  and the last line is

  ```
  module.exports = JSZip;
  ```

If all of that is good, other things to try

- uninstalling and re-installing jszip
- try the install and compile on a clean project
- check your version of angular/cli, make sure it's not too old
- uninstall and re-install angular/cli at global level (-g), then repeat new project test.

BTW, case matters - I notice the SO question where you got the steps has an incorrect case in the constructor call, but that produces a different error.

### **ng version tested with JSZip, imports ok**

```
 test-project>ng version
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.2.0
node: 6.10.3
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.2.4
@angular/common: 4.2.4
@angular/compiler: 4.2.4
@angular/core: 4.2.4
@angular/forms: 4.2.4
@angular/http: 4.2.4
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.7
@angular/platform-browser: 4.2.4
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.2.4
@angular/router: 4.2.4
@angular/cli: 1.2.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.2.4
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Richard,

I have checked your points above and they all appear to be correct and present. I will do an un-install and re-install and see what happens.

One question I cannot solve is what version of angular-cli is jszip expecting? 

Will let you know if a re-install or clean project works

Thanks

Comment: When I run the install I then got these message could one of these be the issue:
ngi-app@2.0.0 C:\wamp\www\ng\public_cli
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.3.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.3.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.3.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@2.3.1
+-- jszip@3.1.4
| +-- core-js@2.3.0
| +-- es6-promise@3.0.2
| +-- lie@3.1.1
| | `-- immediate@3.0.6
| +-- pako@1.0.6
| `-- readable-stream@2.0.6
|   `-- string_decoder@0.10.31
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.3.0
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY tslint@4.3.0

Comment: When you get 'UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY' that means something's not installed. I the above message it looks like most of Angular is not installed. You will have to give exact details about the steps you took.

Comment: Also, my first suggestion was to check various configuration - did you do that?

Comment: Hi Richard, yes I did check all your config points and they were all 100% correct, I have just updated the main post with part of the systemjs.config.js file in case I have done something wrong in this as in the SO post i found about installing JSZip the person mentions editing that file and I was wondering if I have done something wrong.

Comment: Cheers, so if you have a systemjs.config I guess you're not using Angular CLI? I've only used the CLI (which uses webpack) and can report that JSZip imports ok with it. If you want to stick with systemjs, you'll need to research it a bit e.g [SO: What are differences between SystemJS and Webpack ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38263406/what-are-differences-between-systemjs-and-webpack)

Comment: Steps I took were in NPM ran uninstall jszip
closed and re-opened everything made sure the "jszip": "^3.1.4", line was gone from package.json, then ran install and got those messages. 

All my other angular stuff works so not sure why these messages are appearing. As mentioned what version of angular-cli should I be running for jszip?

Comment: I do not believe I am using the systemjs.config.js as I know I am using angular-cli based on my package.json file. I will put my entire package.json file in the section at the top.

Comment: I'll add my angular config to above for reference.

Comment: In your package.json, this looks strange `"angular-cli": {},`. I don't have that line.

Comment: Richard from your angular config i see you are on angular 4 I though from my understanding I could use angular 2 with jszip is this correct from what you know?

Comment: If you are able, I'd definitely recommend updating angular cli as you have quite an old version. If you do, uninstall at global (-g) level and reinstall to get the latest, then start the project anew and all should be good.

Comment: My version details

angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 6.11.2
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 2.3.1
@angular/compiler: 2.3.1
@angular/core: 2.3.1
@angular/forms: 2.3.1
@angular/http: 2.3.1
@angular/platform-browser: 2.3.1
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.3.1
@angular/router: 3.3.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.3.1
PS C:\wamp\www\nationalgrid\public_cli>

Comment: Re Angular 2 vs 4, I'd guess that it makes no difference with a third party lib like jszip.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice and help I will do an update to a newer release and then proceed from there. Thanks again