# Angularjs JSZip to include csv file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jszip

May I ask if any one have any idea how to include a csv file into JSZip? I only know it can have a text file and image folder. How do i include a csv file in it?

My csv download function :

```
<a href="" ng-click="download()">Download</a>

        //Javascript
        function jsonToCsv(headingRows, dataRows) {
        var csv = headingRows.join(',') + '\n';
        csv += dataRows.map(function (row, i) {
        return Object.keys(row).sort().map(function (columnKey) {
        return row[columnKey];
        }).join(',');
        }).join('\n');
        return csv;
        };
        $scope.download = function () {
        var csv = jsonToCsv(['ThemeName', 'DataSharing', 'DisplaySetting', 
        'ExpiryDate', 'Icon', 'PusblishDate','QueryName','ThemeName', 
        'ThemeOwner'], 
        community)
        var csvBlob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv' });
        saveAs(csvBlob, 'data.csv');
        };
        $scope.download1 = function () {
        var csv = jsonToCsv(['ThemeName', 'DataSharing', 'DisplaySetting', 
        'ExpiryDate', 'Icon', 'PusblishDate','QueryName','ThemeName', 
        'ThemeOwner'], sports)
        var csvBlob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv' });
        saveAs(csvBlob, 'data.csv');
        };
```

And the JSZip function:

```
             $scope.create_zip = function () {
          var zip = new JSZip();
          zip.file("Hello.csv", "Hello World\n");

          zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
          .then(function(content) {
              // see FileSaver.js
              saveAs(content, "example.zip");
          });
        }
```

So, what I am trying to ask now is, is there like a way for me to include the current csv download function I have into the JSZip folder? Or any other way for me to include csv file into JSZip.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51537323/angular-2-generate-csv-file-and-download-it-as-zip-file  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62451617/can-we-use-jszip-with-angular7csv-for-zipping-the-multiple-csv-file   i saw similar question with this but there is no proper answer i ever found

Answer (score 0):

```
    let zip = new JSZip();

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var CSV = 'CSV_content ';

    // Fill CSV variable
    zip.file("file" + i + ".csv", CSV);
}
zip.generateAsync({
    type: "base64"
}).then(function(content) {
    window.location.href = "data:application/zip;base64," + content;
});
```

here its creating number CSV file inside  zip folder like

**download.zip** -->

- file 0.csv,
- file 1.csv,
- file 2.csv

whatever content is given in **CSV** will displaying in file.csv make changes according to your need if want to display dynamic CSV file on that you need do these things back-end because of file access not present in the client-side . in back-end create **dir** store CSV and after the download is done remove **dir**

Comment: it zipping the same file five times .Let's consider we have different file , how can we zip it in same folder ??